# Sharepoint 2013 - Copy list Item changes calculated field value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, custom-list, calculated-column-formula

I have a list which triggers a workflow at the end to move the form (copy > delete) to another list. 
The form has a calculated field I am using to give the form a specific reference number. When I copy the list the reference number changes which it CANNOT do. 
Any help would be great. Perhaps a different approach to the reference number issue. Calculated value below:

```
=CONCATENATE("REF-",REPT(0,4-LEN(ID+1)),ID+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculated fields and ID don't work well, as you've found. The copied item will have its own ID, and that's why your ref is changing.

I'd do a mix of calculated fields and workflow.

Create a new field in both lists called OriginalID (or whatever).
In workflow, when a new item is created in the original list, update OriginalID to the actual ID.
Base the calculated field on the OriginalID field instead of the ID field.

Comment: I'll try this and see how I go. Thanks Robin. I will get back to you.